# Spring data @ReadOnlyProperty causing unexpected behavior

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Model attribute that needs to set @ReadOnlyProperty so that it won't persist after first inserting the line.

Assume my model like below

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private String openId;
}
```

then I have a UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

then I provide 2 Restful API for POST and PUT.

The create user operation code is as simple as below:

```
user.setOpenId(1);
userRepository.save(user)
```

The update user operation is almost the same:

```
user.setOpenId(2);
user = userRepository.save(user);
```

I'm surprised that the user's openId attribute will be changed, after POST and then PUT, the returned user object will have the changed value.(user.getOpenId() == 2)

It looks like @ReadOnlyProperty not working, I'm using the RELEASE version of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Can someone help explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `@ReadOnlyProperty` doesn't work. The following bug report is open for years:

[Properties with @ReadOnlyProperty annotation are being nullified in PATCH requests](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-922)

If you want to deny modifying the property via Spring Data Rest endpoints, use the `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` annotation. It affects the JSON deserialization, so the annotated property never reaches Spring Data Rest.

If you also need to deny the writing of the property via Spring Data JPA, you can use the following JPA annotation: `@Column(updatable=false)` It denies the override on the underlaying JPA level, instead of Spring Data JPA level.